# How to get a variable of an object used as a wildcard

Tags: java, generics, wildcard

I am learning java and the topics of generics. To increase my understanding of the wildcard concept I am messing around with the following code. I am trying to make a method that takes a generic class and compare it to the name of a type in a different generic class. It is telling me that name cannot be resolved. How to I create a generic that can access a class instance variable, and also it's self's instance variable? What is wrong with the following code?

```
package wildcardExample;

class tape{
    String name;
    int ItemNum;
}
class paper{
    String name;
    int itemNum;
}
class cds{
    String name;
    int itemNum;
}

class files<T>{
    T myobject;

    files(T inobject){
    myobject = inobject;
}

T returnname(){
    return myobject;
}

static void compareName(files<?> infiles){
    if(this.name == infiles.name){
        System.out.println("name is the same" + this.name);
    }
}
}
public class myWildcard {
    public static void main(String args[]){

    tape MyTape = new tape();
    MyTape.name = "hello world";

    paper MyPaper = new paper();
    MyPaper.name = "hello world";


   files<tape> MyFiles1 = new files<tape>(MyTape);
   files<paper> MyFiles2 = new files<paper>(MyPaper);

   MyFiles1.compareName(MyFiles2);

   }

   }
```

Comment: Among other problems, your `files` class doesn't define a `name` instance variable. Neither `this.name` nor `infiles.name` make any sense.

Comment: "How to I create a generic that can access a class instance variable, and also it's self's instance variable?" You can't. Generics will only give you access to member variables on the erased type - in this case, `Object`, which has no public fields.

Comment: How do I declare a name instance variable in the files generic? What would I do to fix this code?

Comment: Your code would be more readable if you fixed your capitalization; class names should be UpperCamelCase while variables should be lowerCamelCase.

Comment: member variables on the erased type? can you explain to me what this is? I am just learning this topic.

Comment: One problem you've got here is that `static` methods can't use `this`.

Comment: @ThomasThornier There is a naming convention for Java code. Please take a look http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html

Comment: You're probably better off getting a general handle on writing Java code and _using_ generics. Then _writing_ generic classes will come somewhat easier, when you need it.

Answer (score 0):

You can't access member variables of unrelated classes with generics.

Java generics work using a concept called *type erasure*. This basically means that when the code is compiled, all of the generics are removed by the compiler, and you're left with "non-generic" code, using the erased type of the type variable.

In the case of your `class files<T>`, the erased type of `T` is `Object` (`T` is a shorthand for `T extends Object`). So, you code can only access member variables and methods from `Object`. But `Object` has no publicly-visible member variables, so you can't access any member variables on the generic variables.

The correct approach here is to make each of your types implement some interface:

```
interface SomeInterface {
  String name();
  int itemNum();
}

class tape implements SomeInterface {
  String name;
  int ItemNum;

  @Override public String name() { return name; }
  @Override public int itemNum() { return ItemNum; }
}

// etc.
```

and then use `SomeInterface` as an upper bound for your generics:

```
class files<T extends SomeInterface>
```

Now you can invoke `name()` and `itemNum()` on `myobject`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like the following right?

```
package wildcardExample;

class Thing {
    String name;
    int ItemNum;
}
class Tape extends Thing { }
class Paper extends Thing { }
class CDs extends Thing { }

class Files<T extends Thing>{
    T myobject; // this way you will ensure that myobject has name field since it instance of type Thing (or any subclass of Thing)
    Files(T inobject){
        myobject = inobject;
    }

    T returnName(){
        return myobject;
    }

    void compareName(Files<?> infiles){
        // you cannot use this in a static method since this method doesn't belong to the object but to the class
        if(this.name == infiles.name){
            System.out.println("name is the same" + this.name);
        }
    }
}
public class MyWildcard {
    public static void main(String args[]){

        Tape MyTape = new Tape();
        MyTape.name = "hello world";

        Paper MyPaper = new Paper();
        MyPaper.name = "hello world";


        Files<Tape> MyFiles1 = new Files<Tape>(MyTape);
        Files<Paper> MyFiles2 = new Files<Paper>(MyPaper);

        MyFiles1.compareName(MyFiles2);

    }

}
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: If I add the method to the Thing class it should work?

Comment: if you mean as static then no, since if you want it as a static method you would have to have two Files objects as parameters instead of one
and if you mean adding it directly without static then yes but you would not need the generics anymore.

Comment: Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access a variable (`name`) that isn't a member of the `files<T>` class.

Since you are trying to compare the names of the types passed in for (in)equality, you need to be sure of the type being passed.

In your case, `T` can be anything and thus you cannot invoke a member as the type/object isn't known.

What you could do, is to bound `T` to something that is guaranteed to have the member you are looking for, i.e.

`files<T extends {class/interface}>` is referred to as an upper bound where the class/interface defines the upper bound/top of inheritance tree, thereby ensuring that it contains the member you are looking for.

Code which demonstrates this and behaves as you intend it to is as shown:

```
public class Temp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Paper paper = new Paper();
        paper.setName("name");

        Tape tape = new Tape();
        tape.setName("name");

        Generic<Paper> gen1 = new Generic(paper);
        Generic<Tape> gen2 = new Generic(tape);

        System.out.println(gen1.compare(gen2));
    }
}

interface Tester {
    void setName(String name);

    String getName();
}

class Paper implements Tester {
    String name;

    @Override
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}

class Tape implements Tester {
    String name;

    @Override
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}

// The extends keyword is used to indicate an upper bound
// which refers to any class that extends/implements Tester
// is a valid type argument to the Generic class.
// It helps to use the methods that Tester declares

class Generic<T extends Tester> {
    T type;

    Generic(T type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    boolean compare(Generic<? extends Tester> generic) {
        return this.type.getName().equals(generic.type.getName());
    }
}
```

Following code conventions is a good practice.

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

This seems to do what I want

```
package wildcardExample;

class Thing {
    String name;
    int ItemNum;

    boolean comparethings(Thing mything){
        if(this.name == mything.name){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }

    }
}
class Tape extends Thing { }
class Paper extends Thing { }
class CDs extends Thing { }

class Files<T extends Thing>{
    T myobject; // this way you will ensure that myobject has name field since it instance of type Thing (or any subclass of Thing)
    Files(T inobject){
        myobject = inobject;
    }

    T returnName(){
        return myobject;
    }

    boolean compareName(Files<?> infiles){
        // you cannot use this in a static method since this method doesn't belong to the object but to the class
        boolean myboo = myobject.comparethings(infiles.myobject);
        return myboo;
    }
}
public class myWildcard {
    public static void main(String args[]){

        Tape MyTape = new Tape();
        MyTape.name = "hello world";

        Paper MyPaper = new Paper();
        MyPaper.name = "hello world";


        Files<Tape> MyFiles1 = new Files<Tape>(MyTape);
        Files<Paper> MyFiles2 = new Files<Paper>(MyPaper);

        System.out.println(MyFiles1.compareName(MyFiles2));

    }

}
```